# python - remove all decimals from a float

Tags: python

How can I remove all decimal places form a float?

`a = 100.0`

I want that to become 100

I tried `str(a).rstrip('.0')`, but it just returned `1`

Comment: A float will always contain decimal places, best to change to an int

Comment: Worth pointing out that `'.0'` != `.0`. One is a `string` the other is a `float`.

Comment: As always, reading [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) helps (to avoid going certain paths at least): *"Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed."* So if you do `rstrip('.0')`, it removes all occurrences of `.` and `0` from the end of the string.

Comment: @FelixKling You know? Somewhere in my mind I was sure that you could truncate decimals strings with this `rstrip` trick. Answering now and reading that in the docs just made me realize I was so wrong :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about converting it to `int`?

```
>>>int(a)
100
```

Just for the sake of completeness, there are many many ways to remove the decimal part from a string representation of a decimal number, one that I can come up right now is:

```
s='100.0'
s=s[:s.index('.')]
s
>>>'100'
```

Perhaps there's another one more simple.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to abuse the `os.path` library: `s = '100.0'; print os.path.splitext(s)[0] # 100`.  This takes advantage of the fact that a decimal looks like a file extension.

Comment: `s,_,_ = s.partition('.')` seems simplest.  Or even `s,*_ = s.partition('.')` in py3.

Comment: `os.path` is quite clever but I think others looking at the code would had a hard time to understand its intentions. I saw `partition` before posting this, but liked more with slicing, it's just my opinion :) Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @PauloBu I completely agree.  I would never actually use that, but I wanted to be clever as you say.  In real code one should use `int`, or maybe `'{:.0f}'.format(100.0)` if they want a string.

Comment: What if I want 100.25 to become 10025?

Comment: @sh.3.ll multiply by a 100? `int(100.25 * 100)`. If it is a string, then replace() method and get rid of the dot

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to convert it to an int you can also split it.

```
>>> a = 100.25
>>> str(a).split('.')[0]
>>> '100'  # result is now a string
```

Comment: anyone could explain me the downvote? It's just an alternative method!

Comment: Probably because it's an extremely inferior "solution".

Comment: I provided a correct solution to his string approach by trying to remove decimals with string methods. The quesiton didn't state the data type of the answer.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `str(int(a))` is still a strictly better method if you want to end up with a string.  There's just no need for `split`.

Comment: Totally agree with the last. int(a) is a much better approach, but as the person questioning was trying to almost literally "cut" a part I thought a possible approach, he could learn for future problem with "cutting". Tx for the up.

Comment: I also like to keep the OPs' way of thinking while suggesting better ways. Finding a way to truncate it with string is perfectly valid, downvoting wasn't necessary IMHO.

Comment: By the way Paulo is it possible that "str(100.25).split('.')[0]" is faster than "int(100.25)"? I tried with timeit, and had better results with strings, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably is, haven't benchmarked it, although _it shouldn't_, taking into accounts the number of operations they have to do.

Comment: yeah, in windows gives me better results but in my Raspberry Pi, int conversion is better, something to do with core management?

Comment: Ok so now I did and they both behave almost identically. With larger numbers `int()` version is little faster. It would be interesting to investigate further :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're deriving the float you can floor it with //

```
a = 200 / 2 # outputs 100.0
a = 200 // 2 # outputs 100
```

Faster than typecasting afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,`int()` method in python is the type conversion function similar to `float()` and `str()`, and can be used for converting float numbers to int numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 100.0
new_a = int(100.0) #removing all the decimals after floating point
print(new_a, ",", type(new_a))
```

output:

```
100 , <class 'int'>
```

And for omitting a specific number of decimals after floating point:

```
a = 100.123
k = 2 #number of decimals after floating point we want to keep
new_a = round(a, k) #just storing k decimals after floating point
print(new_a, ",", type(new_a))
```

output:

```
100.12 , <class 'float'>
```